# Compare AM and PM for filtering

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to create a list of persons (guides) with several conditions.

If a guide is already occupied in that moment of the day (which I want to divide in 2: AM or PM) he has to be filtered.

This is the part where I want to compare the moment of the day

```
oReservationDetailGuide.tblReservationDetail.StartTime.Value.Date.ToString("tt") != dDate.Date.ToString("tt"))
```

It has to check that the moments of the day are not equal (AM/PM).
    AM != PM (true)
    PM != AM (true)
    AM == AM (false)
    PM == PM (false)

but how can I get just 'AM' or 'PM' out of my date? Because .ToString("tt") gives nothing back as result.

Comment: By the time you've simplified this code enough to ask a question It should be obvious what's going wrong. But this code is really hard to read and probably far to complex for what its doing.

Comment: Just as an aside - LINQ uses deferred execution. You probably should break out some of that sub-query logic into separate query variables so the whole mess is more understandable.

Comment: Are you just trying to compare whether a time is AM or PM? If so why convert to a string at all and not just check against a Datetime value of 12pm?

Comment: The last snippet of code is all you need to show ...

Comment: sorry guys, I have seriously shortened the question. Hope this gives a better idea of what I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would format your times like so: `"0:hh:mm:ss.F t"`

But I think you'll see that a single `t` is what formats AM/PM.

Comment: It doens't work. How can I just get AM/PM as output without anything else?

Answer (score 0):

1. For comparing dates better use DateTime.Compare Method
   [enter link description here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.compare.aspx?ppud=4)
2. Your query is very big and hard to support by someone and by you in next month (because of when you will see the huge query after some pause you WILL NOT want make any changes - this query is spooky).

Good luck

Comment: thx, but I don't need to compare hours, just want to check if the guides are not yet occupied in that moment of the day, noted as AM or PM